# Doctrine 2 not creating foreign key

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have this piece of code inside an Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Centers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="center_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=36, name="center_id")
 */
protected $centerId;
```

However, `schema:update` says that all is in sync. Even changing Centers to some other inexistent word, produces no error.

Comment: What was the code before? What did you change? Why do you expect it to behave a certain way?

Comment: Have you tried to clear the cache?

Comment: @k0pernikus I've added that code, I was expecting a query to create the foreign key

Comment: @DanCostinel Nothing changed after clearing cache

Comment: @JorgeeFG To me, it seems you are not undestanding how doctrine as a ORM works. They annotate relationships with *entities*, you don't add foreign key fields manually. Look at the example of [doctrine's documenation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)

Comment: @k0pernikus I don't understand, I did the same as the documentation, added the annotations and ran (in symfony) doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql and no `ALTER TABLE ADD FOREIGN KEY...` sentence is made. `Centers` is another Entity with annotations.

Comment: I think you need to remove the line with `@ORM\Column...`. Try it.

Comment: @DanCostinel yes that worked! So I guess Doctrine is looking at the other table to figure out type

Comment: Yep, I think doctrine manages the creation and the type of the foreign key based on your `JoinColumn(..., referencedColumnName=...)` option. The default behaviour is to reference the `id` of the targetEntity. And any error thrown, as I'm aware, is ignored by doctrine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please **delete the last line** of annotation doctrine like this and change $centerId by $center (there is object an object) :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Centers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="center_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $center;
```

Clear cache and run your command.

Tell me if this solved your problem.

Comment: this add forigne key to table but i can;t delete -> Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: My problem solved by add `onDelete="CASCADE"` to `JoinColumn`